# List of all recipes of mathematical notation

Tags: traditional-form, input-forms, notation, named-characters, input-alias

Where can I find all the recipes of mathematical notations? Or the ways of direct input of the traditional forms? Not convert to traditional forms, but input them directly.

For example, the recipe for `D[f,x]` is `Esc`+pd+`Esc`+`Ctrl`+`_`+x+f.

By the way, what is the recipe for `Derivative[1, 0][f]`?

Comment: Maybe this?: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html

Comment: It doesn't help. There is no recipe for `Derivative[1, 0][f]`.

Comment: There is no recipe for `Derivative[1, 0][f]`, is there?

Comment: I don't know, too. But on the wolfram language webpage https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/pdes-and-finite-elements/solve-a-wave-equation-in-2d.html , it seems there is such a recipe, which seems to be  f+`Ctrl`+`^`+(1,0). However, it didn't work.

Comment: I believe that is the ***output*** formatting, not input formatting, of `Derivative`. The only shortcut for `Derivative` mentioned in the docs is the use of primes to denote single-variable derivatives, `Derivative[1]`, `Derivative[2]`, etc. The output of `D[f[x,y], x]` contains a `TagBox` that identifies the superscript as a `Derivative`. A similar problem exists for `InverseFunction`, which is output with `(-1)` as a superscript. This is mentioned in the documentation for `TagBox`.